# Update tensor with arrays in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a 3-D tensor in which I want to update some values the same way as in this numpy code:

```
x_np = np.zeros((2,3,2))
updates_np = np.ones((2,2))
indices_1 = np.array([0, 1])
indices_2 = np.array([1, 1])

x_np[indices_1, indices_2, :] = updates_np
```

and this is the result:

```
>>> x_np

array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
```

as you can I want to update full rows on the last dimension, so to do that I'm trying to use [scatter_update](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_update) (and I also tried with [dynamic_stitch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/dynamic_stitch)). But it seems that scatter_update doesn't accept more than one dimension as the updates indices.

How can I do this in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

I came with a solution which to me looks awful, so any improvements are welcome

```
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
x = tf.zeros((2,3,2))
indices_1 = tf.constant([0, 1])
indices_2 = tf.constant([1, 1])
updates_tf = tf.ones((2, 2))  

x_temp = tf.Variable(tf.reshape(x, [-1, 2]))

indices_flat = tf.shape(x)[1]*indices_1 + indices_2
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
print(sess.run(tf.reshape(tf.scatter_update(x_temp, indices_flat,  updates_tf), tf.shape(x))))
```

Result

```
[[[ 0.  0.]
  [ 1.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  0.]
  [ 1.  1.]
  [ 0.  0.]]]
```